# Stopping a Java Thread with heavy DB operations

Tags: java, multithreading, deprecated, interrupt

I'm using a third party library in my thread which involves some heavy DB operations . 
Sometimes due to the lock on the DB or any other reasons execution of thread gets stuck . I want to kill the thread irrespective of what it is doing after the particular time interval.
Thread.interrupt() is not working out for  me because my thread spend most of its time in the  third party library which i can't modify and library doesn't throw any Interrupted Exception which i can handle in my code. 
Thread.stop() is not advised to use since it is deprecated .
But i have to kill the thread anyway

```
void mainThread()
{
  Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
  t1.start();
  Thread.sleep(time);
  if(t1.getState() != State.TERMINATED)
  {
    // code for killing the thread
  }
}

Thread1()
{
    //doing heavy DB operations using third party Library
}
```

Any suggestion for other designs is welcomed . 
 Is there any alternate method for killing a thread instead of thread.stop()

Comment: You cannot (or better, you should not) kill a running Thread in Java. You should handle the locking reasons in the Thread itself and properly exit the when appropriate. Anyway, DB locking is usually temporary, I don't think a Thread can starve over a DB lock (if other software locking the DB is aware that other software is using the DB too, that is). I think your problem maybe lying in some interlocking you didn't consider. Does this Thread wait for other Threads or does some inter-threading communications?

Comment: some other program are also using the same DB and they can have created the lock because of that mt thread  keeps waiting . I cant handle the locks or DB code since it is implemented in the third party library

Comment: Instead of finding a patch to your problem why not solve it? If the third party app is hanging things up then ditch it. Use a connection pool and JDBC to do your query and hook it up with exceptions just in case. The last thing you want to do is give control of your app to a library that doesen't function properly.

Comment: But that other program has to release the DB lock eventually. If it doesn't (which IMHO is a bug), then no other program can run over this DB when this third-party app is running.

Comment: because of some restrictions i cant take my own JDBC connection . That third party app has this bug but i have to use this app anyway . there must be a way to kill the thread without using the Thread.stop()

Comment: If the third-party app locks the DB and never releases it, there's no way you can even query the DB from anything outside this app, so why even bother in spawning the thread?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your DB access in a [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and get the result using [`FutureTask.get(long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) (it will return before the supplied time, or throw a `TimeoutException`).

Read Chapter 6 of [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) by Brian Goetz et al for more info

Comment: depending on number of objects to fetch i can't set a particular time every time thread wants to access the DB . Number of object from DB can vary from 10 to 100K .

Comment: @gauravsingh ok, so calculate the wait time based on the number of objects, e.g. `futureTask.get(numberOfObjectsExpected / 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd while this is true, the underlying task - callable or runnable will still execute. You can't stop the thread once it started. He said that the library will not respond to interrupts of flags.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd interrupt only works when thread handles the interrupt or code throws the InterruptedException . FutureTask only interrupts the thread

Answer (score 0):

if the library that you are using is *that broker (it does not handle interrupts or stop flags)*, then you can't do much. Actually you can't do anything, **unless Thread.stop**.

You might want to use it, but, specially since we are talking about a database, it could and will most probably, leave the database in a very inconsistent state. You might not even notice it, it could pop-up in 10 years from now.

My advice is : fix the library that you use, or have someone to fix it OR *take your risk* and stop the thread (kill it) and face the consequences.